# Interactive plot of pandas columns using python

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, holoviews

I have a table as follows:

```python
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(24,53)))
df['hour'] = range(24)
for col in df.columns[:-1]:
    df.rename({col: str(col)}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

which I want to plot. Columns (except `hour`) correspond to *weeks of the year* and rows to *hours of the day*. Directly using pandas it would be:

```
df[df.columns[:-1]].plot(legend=False);
```

yielding:

[image: Plot using pandas]

However, I want to add interactivity into the game. I thought of using `bokeh` but it changes so rapidly, I don't know how to do it now. I tried using `holoviews`:

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
%%opts Curve [tools=['hover']]
lines = [hv.Curve((df['hour'], df[col]), label=col) for col in df.columns[:-1]]

from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, lines) # I'm not sure this is a clean way
```

yielding something like:

[image]

This is doing *almost* what I want. In particular, the hover tool, shows the x/y coordinates of the points under it. I want it to show the week of the corresponding curve. Lastly, is there a more pythonic way to do so? Maybe directly with `bokeh`?

Comment: Note that Bokeh is having a final few changes before a 1.0 release scheduled for next month (before SciPy 2018), and the API is set to be stable after that. What's currently being addressed shouldn't affect anything major, so Bokeh shouldn't be a moving target any more.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at the new [holoplot](https://pyviz.github.io/holoplot/index.html) project which is meant to be (almost) a drop-in replacement for the pandas plotting API built on HoloViews and Bokeh. That will allow you do use the regular pandas API:

```
import holoplot.pandas
df[df.columns[:-1]].plot(legend=False)
```

[image]

Note that it is still in active development. Separately for the sake of completeness the simpler way to express your HoloViews code would be:

```
lines = [hv.Curve((df['hour'], df[col]), label=col) for col in df.columns[:-1]]
hv.Overlay(lines)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is nice and seems to work. Do you know how to limit the scope of `holoplot` to a single plot? Now it seems like it highjacked the standard `pandas` plotting.

Comment: That's a good question, currently there's no way to do that but I definitely think there should be. Would you mind filing an issue on https://github.com/pyviz/holoplot to get discussion on that going?

Comment: Done. can you add some details on how to adjust the hover tool?

Comment: Could you elaborate? If you mean that you want the same hover tooltip as shown above, I'll be pushing a fix for that shortly and release a new version tomorrow.

Comment: I recall that in pure bokeh you can adjust the hover tool and configure what is the text, what is shown etc. Is it possible using holoplot?